# Openlayers Google V3 doesn't load main.js

Tags: google-maps-api-3, openlayers

under some conditions (that only god or google knows), this is not sufficient to provide the js tag...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

... in order to load the Google V3 API. I must provide in these cases the following tag that loads the corresponding main.js:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=" http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/pt_br/mapfiles/api-3/8/7/main.js"></script>
```

Because this file doesn't load automatically from the first script.

Do someone already experienced the same behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Probably that's because you don't specify api-version in script tag. This works fine for me:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.5&amp;sensor=false"></script>
```